# How to mock a service in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

```
IUpdateServiceInterface Updateinfo = null;


private ServiceConnection ServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Updateinfo = IUpdateServiceinterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
            mCountdownLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            System.out.println("testing me");
            Updateinfo = null;
            mCountdownLatch.countDown();
        }
    };
```

is there any sample i can follow to try and start service on the listener for mockito unit test kotlin

any help thanks much appreciated

Comment: What are you working with? Generally, I would reccomend MockK for kotlin, as it is mockito retailered for kotlin. If you are using Spring, then I also reccomend ninjasquad's springmockk. To give you a solid answer, we need a little bit more context.